# Lambda request body parsing issue using AWS api gateway

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, mailgun

I am facing an issue while receiving a request from Mailgun, which contains an email attribute in the request body. I have deployed an AWS lambda function along with an API gateway. When a request comes through the AWS API gateway, it encodes the body content and passes the request to the Lambda function, but my lambda function couldn’t decode the content in such a way to consume through our implementation.

I have tested my implementation without using the AWS API gateway, and it works, but it doesn't work along with the AWS API gateway.

When I'm converting request body content that comes through the API gateway, which was encoded by the API gateway but I can't convert the request body in the form to consume it.

After decoded, I am getting this -

```
Base64.strict_decode64(base64string)


"Content-Type=multipart%2Falternative%3B+boundary%3D%22772a87c3bfe6815a93e5a01ac72bf6f3304ff90d08696b62b907422a03a3%22&Date=Fri%2C+13+Jan+2023+10%3A44%3A06+%2B0000&From=VueOps+Warranty+Ticket+%3Cservice-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com%3E&In-Reply-To%5B%5D=20230113104406.86d5542bf7d85f30%40mg.vueops-qa.com&Message-Id=%3C20230113104406.962d120183579f0f%40mg.vueops-qa.com%3E&Mime-Version=1.0&Sender=service-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com&Subject=Warranty+Ticket+SUM-EST-0204+for+Email+Subject+Test+edit+for+Sumit%27s+Test+has+been+issued+to+you+for+coordination&To=service-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com&body-html=%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Cmeta+content%3D%22text%2Fhtml%3B+charset%3Dutf-8%22+http-equiv%3D%22Content-Type%22%3E%0A%3Cstyle%3Ebody+%7B%0Afont-family%3A+%27Calibri%27%2C+%27Arial%27%2C+sans-serif%3B%0A%7D%0Aimg+%7B%0Aoutline%3A+none%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B+-ms-interpolation-mode%3A+bicubic%3B%0A%7D%0A%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody+style%3D%22font-family%3A+%27Calibri%27%2C+%27Arial%27%2C+sans-serif%3B%22%3E%0A%3Ctable+align%3D%22center%22+cellpadding%3D%220%22+cellspacing%3D%220%22+class%3D%22logo%22+width%3D%22100%25%22%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd+align%3D%22left%22%3E%3Cimg+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fdpr-email-assets%2FVueOPS-logo-full-color-ps.png%22+style%3D%22outline%3A+none%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B+-ms-interpolation-mode%3A+bicubic%3B+width%3A+120px%3B%22%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++Hello%2C%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3E%0A++++A+new+Warranty+Ticket+has+been+issued+for+Email+Subject+Test+edit+for+Sumit%27s+Test.%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EPlease+follow+the+steps+below+to+resolve+this+issue.%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ESTEP+1%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++Contact+the+client+contact+noted+below+for+scheduling+your+inspection+and+repair.+You+may+contact+the+client+by+phone+or+by+replying-all+to+this+email.%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong+style%3D%22font-size%3A+1.1em%3B%22%3EWarranty+Ticket+Details%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ETicket+%23%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+SUM-EST-0204%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EClient%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Sumit%27s+Test%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EFacility%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Email+Subject+Test+edit%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EProject%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+118+docs%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ETitle%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Perferendis+voluptat%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EDescription%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+In+excepteur+aliquid%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ELocation%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Sed+sint+nihil+moles%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EPriority%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Emergency%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstring%3EYou+can+view+the+ticket+details+here%3A%3C%2Fstring%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Ca+ng-href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204%22+class%3D%22ng-binding%22+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204%22+style%3D%22color%3A+%232e74b5%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B%22%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204%3C%2Fa%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EFacility+Address%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cspan+ng-bind-html%3D%22serviceRequest.formattedFacilityAddress%22+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3EMetro+Street%3Cbr%3EB+23+Street%3Cbr%3ENoida+City%2C+NCR+State+110092%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EClient+Contact+Information%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EName%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Sumit+Vueops+Account%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EEmail%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+sumitka%40vueops.com%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EPhone+Number%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+999-687-4668%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ESTEP+2%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++When+the+repair+work+is+complete+we+ask+that+you+respond+to+this+email+with+the+following+information+and+a+photo+of+the+completed+work%3A%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EWork+Performed%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ERoot+Cause%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ERepair+Date%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%0A+%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cdiv+class%3D%22footer%22+style%3D%22font-size%3A+10pt%3B+font-family%3A+%27FrnkGothITC+Bk+BT%27%2C+%27Calibri%27%2C+%27Arial%27%2C+sans-serif%3B+color%3A+%23999999%3B+letter-spacing%3A+2pt%3B%22%3E%3Cp%3EThank+You%2C+%3Cbr%3EPowered+by+%3Ca+href%3D%22www.vueops.com%22+style%3D%22color%3A+%232e74b5%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B%22%3EVueOps%3C%2Fa%3E%3Cbr%3EKnow+Your+Building+Inside+Out%3Csup%3ETM%3Csup%3E%3C%2Fsup%3E%3C%2Fsup%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A&body-plain=Hello%2C%0A%0AA+new+Warranty+Ticket+has+been+issued+for+Email+Subject+Test+edit+for+Sumit%27s+Test.%0APlease+follow+the+steps+below+to+resolve+this+issue.%0A%0ASTEP+1%3A%0AContact+the+client+contact+noted+below+for+scheduling+your+inspection+and+repair.+You+may+contact+the+client+by+phone+or+by+replying-all+to+this+email.%0A%0AWarranty+Ticket+Details%3A%0A%0ATicket+%23%3A+SUM-EST-0204%0A%0AClient%3A+Sumit%27s+Test%0A%0AFacility%3A+Email+Subject+Test+edit%0A%0AProject%3A+118+docs%0A%0ATitle%3A+Perferendis+voluptat%0A%0ADescription%3A+In+excepteur+aliquid%0A%0ALocation%3A+Sed+sint+nihil+moles%0A%0APriority%3A+Emergency%0A%0AYou+can+view+the+ticket+details+here%3A%0A%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204+%28+https%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204+%29%0A%0AFacility+Address%3A%0A%0AMetro+Street%0AB+23+Street%0ANoida+City%2C+NCR+State+110092%0A%0AClient+Contact+Information%0A%0AName%3A+Sumit+Vueops+Account%0A%0AEmail%3A+sumitka%40vueops.com%0A%0APhone+Number%3A+999-687-4668%0A%0ASTEP+2%3A%0AWhen+the+repair+work+is+complete+we+ask+that+you+respond+to+this+email+with+the+following+information+and+a+photo+of+the+completed+work%3A%0A%0AWork+Performed%0A%0ARoot+Cause%3A%0A%0ARepair+Date%3A%0A%0AThank+You%2C%0APowered+by+VueOps+%28+www.vueops.com+%29%0AKnow+Your+Building+Inside+OutTM&from=VueOps+Warranty+Ticket+%3Cservice-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com%3E&message-headers=%5B%5B%22Mime-Version%22%2C%221.0%22%5D%2C%5B%22Content-Type%22%2C%22multipart%2Falternative%3B+boundary%3D%5C%22772a87c3bfe6815a93e5a01ac72bf6f3304ff90d08696b62b907422a03a3%5C%22%22%5D%2C%5B%22Subject%22%2C%22Warranty+Ticket+SUM-EST-0204+for+Email+Subject+Test+edit+for+Sumit%27s+Test+has+been+issued+to+you+for+coordination%22%5D%2C%5B%22From%22%2C%22VueOps+Warranty+Ticket+%3Cservice-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com%3E%22%5D%2C%5B%22To%22%2C%22service-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com%22%5D%2C%5B%22In-Reply-To%5B%5D%22%2C%2220230113104406.86d5542bf7d85f30%40mg.vueops-qa.com%22%5D%2C%5B%22Message-Id%22%2C%22%3C20230113104406.962d120183579f0f%40mg.vueops-qa.com%3E%22%5D%2C%5B%22Date%22%2C%22Fri%2C+13+Jan+2023+10%3A44%3A06+%2B0000%22%5D%2C%5B%22Sender%22%2C%22service-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com%22%5D%5D&recipient=service-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com&sender=VueOps+Warranty+Ticket+%3Cservice-requests-qa%40mg.vueops-qa.com%3E&signature=69257cd5ebdff97507389baaa401c9f7d370b25e43135c8695342b676412ac42&stripped-html=%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Cmeta+content%3D%22text%2Fhtml%3B+charset%3Dutf-8%22+http-equiv%3D%22Content-Type%22%3E%0A%3Cstyle%3Ebody+%7B%0Afont-family%3A+%27Calibri%27%2C+%27Arial%27%2C+sans-serif%3B%0A%7D%0Aimg+%7B%0Aoutline%3A+none%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B+-ms-interpolation-mode%3A+bicubic%3B%0A%7D%0A%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody+style%3D%22font-family%3A+%27Calibri%27%2C+%27Arial%27%2C+sans-serif%3B%22%3E%0A%3Ctable+align%3D%22center%22+cellpadding%3D%220%22+cellspacing%3D%220%22+class%3D%22logo%22+width%3D%22100%25%22%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd+align%3D%22left%22%3E%3Cimg+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fdpr-email-assets%2FVueOPS-logo-full-color-ps.png%22+style%3D%22outline%3A+none%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B+-ms-interpolation-mode%3A+bicubic%3B+width%3A+120px%3B%22%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++Hello%2C%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3E%0A++++A+new+Warranty+Ticket+has+been+issued+for+Email+Subject+Test+edit+for+Sumit%27s+Test.%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EPlease+follow+the+steps+below+to+resolve+this+issue.%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ESTEP+1%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++Contact+the+client+contact+noted+below+for+scheduling+your+inspection+and+repair.+You+may+contact+the+client+by+phone+or+by+replying-all+to+this+email.%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong+style%3D%22font-size%3A+1.1em%3B%22%3EWarranty+Ticket+Details%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ETicket+%23%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+SUM-EST-0204%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EClient%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Sumit%27s+Test%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EFacility%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Email+Subject+Test+edit%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EProject%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+118+docs%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ETitle%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Perferendis+voluptat%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EDescription%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+In+excepteur+aliquid%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ELocation%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Sed+sint+nihil+moles%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EPriority%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Emergency%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstring%3EYou+can+view+the+ticket+details+here%3A%3C%2Fstring%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Ca+ng-href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204%22+class%3D%22ng-binding%22+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204%22+style%3D%22color%3A+%232e74b5%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B%22%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204%3C%2Fa%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EFacility+Address%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cspan+ng-bind-html%3D%22serviceRequest.formattedFacilityAddress%22+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3EMetro+Street%3Cbr%3EB+23+Street%3Cbr%3ENoida+City%2C+NCR+State+110092%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EClient+Contact+Information%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EName%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+Sumit+Vueops+Account%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EEmail%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+sumitka%40vueops.com%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EPhone+Number%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E+999-687-4668%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ESTEP+2%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++When+the+repair+work+is+complete+we+ask+that+you+respond+to+this+email+with+the+following+information+and+a+photo+of+the+completed+work%3A%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3EWork+Performed%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ERoot+Cause%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A++++%3Cbr%3E%0A++++%3Cstrong%3ERepair+Date%3A%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%0A++++%0A+%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cdiv+class%3D%22footer%22+style%3D%22font-size%3A+10pt%3B+font-family%3A+%27FrnkGothITC+Bk+BT%27%2C+%27Calibri%27%2C+%27Arial%27%2C+sans-serif%3B+color%3A+%23999999%3B+letter-spacing%3A+2pt%3B%22%3E%3Cp%3EThank+You%2C+%3Cbr%3EPowered+by+%3Ca+href%3D%22www.vueops.com%22+style%3D%22color%3A+%232e74b5%3B+text-decoration%3A+none%3B%22%3EVueOps%3C%2Fa%3E%3Cbr%3EKnow+Your+Building+Inside+Out%3Csup%3ETM%3Csup%3E%3C%2Fsup%3E%3C%2Fsup%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A&stripped-signature=Work+Performed%0A%0ARoot+Cause%3A%0A%0ARepair+Date%3A%0A%0AThank+You%2C%0APowered+by+VueOps+%28+www.vueops.com+%29%0AKnow+Your+Building+Inside+OutTM&stripped-text=Hello%2C%0A%0AA+new+Warranty+Ticket+has+been+issued+for+Email+Subject+Test+edit+for+Sumit%27s+Test.%0APlease+follow+the+steps+below+to+resolve+this+issue.%0A%0ASTEP+1%3A%0AContact+the+client+contact+noted+below+for+scheduling+your+inspection+and+repair.+You+may+contact+the+client+by+phone+or+by+replying-all+to+this+email.%0A%0AWarranty+Ticket+Details%3A%0A%0ATicket+%23%3A+SUM-EST-0204%0A%0AClient%3A+Sumit%27s+Test%0A%0AFacility%3A+Email+Subject+Test+edit%0A%0AProject%3A+118+docs%0A%0ATitle%3A+Perferendis+voluptat%0A%0ADescription%3A+In+excepteur+aliquid%0A%0ALocation%3A+Sed+sint+nihil+moles%0A%0APriority%3A+Emergency%0A%0AYou+can+view+the+ticket+details+here%3A%0A%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204+%28+https%3A%2F%2Fsumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com%2Fservice_requests%2Fsum-est-0204+%29%0A%0AFacility+Address%3A%0A%0AMetro+Street%0AB+23+Street%0ANoida+City%2C+NCR+State+110092%0A%0AClient+Contact+Information%0A%0AName%3A+Sumit+Vueops+Account%0A%0AEmail%3A+sumitka%40vueops.com%0A%0APhone+Number%3A+999-687-4668%0A%0ASTEP+2%3A%0AWhen+the+repair+work+is+complete+we+ask+that+you+respond+to+this+email+with+the+following+information+and+a+photo+of+the+completed+work%3A%0A&subject=Warranty+Ticket+SUM-EST-0204+for+Email+Subject+Test+edit+for+Sumit%27s+Test+has+been+issued+to+you+for+coordination&timestamp=1673613697&token=9e50b9d3b4b4cfac741c4e0a7d154ca9b52a69146937cc2ba4"
```

which should be like this -

```
{"Content-Type"=>"multipart/alternative; boundary=\"0d4b5135bbc71f7078e98fd7ee7355506fb2c219e22a702a301bd7123e55\"", "Date"=>"Fri, 13 Jan 2023 18:31:51 +0000", "From"=>"VueOps Warranty Ticket <service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com>", "In-Reply-To"=>["20230113183151.bad48c4ced209202@mg.vueops-qa.com"], "Message-Id"=>"<20230113183151.74967e8866be2d25@mg.vueops-qa.com>", "Mime-Version"=>"1.0", "Sender"=>"service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com", "Subject"=>"Warranty Ticket SUM-EST-0204 for Email Subject Test edit for Sumit's Test has been issued to you for coordination", "To"=>"service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com", "body-html"=>"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\">\n<style>body {\nfont-family: 'Calibri', 'Arial', sans-serif;\n}\nimg {\noutline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body style=\"font-family: 'Calibri', 'Arial', sans-serif;\">\n<table align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"logo\" width=\"100%\"><tr><td align=\"left\"><img src=\"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dpr-email-assets/VueOPS-logo-full-color-ps.png\" style=\"outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: 120px;\"></td></tr></table>\n<p></p>\n<p>\n    Hello,\n</p>\n<p class=\"ng-binding\">\n    A new Warranty Ticket has been issued for Email Subject Test edit for Sumit's Test.\n    <strong>Please follow the steps below to resolve this issue.</strong>\n</p>\n<p>\n    <br>\n    <strong>STEP 1:</strong>\n    Contact the client contact noted below for scheduling your inspection and repair. You may contact the client by phone or by replying-all to this email.\n    <br>\n</p>\n<p class=\"ng-binding\">\n    <strong style=\"font-size: 1.1em;\">Warranty Ticket Details:</strong>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Ticket #:</strong> SUM-EST-0204\n    <br>\n    <strong>Client:</strong> Sumit's Test\n    <br>\n    <strong>Facility:</strong> Email Subject Test edit\n    <br>\n    <strong>Project:</strong> 118 docs\n    <br>\n    <strong>Title:</strong> Perferendis voluptat\n    <br>\n    <strong>Description:</strong> In excepteur aliquid\n    <br>\n    <strong>Location:</strong> Sed sint nihil moles\n    <br>\n    <strong>Priority:</strong> Emergency\n    <br>\n    <string>You can view the ticket details here:</string>\n    <br><br>\n    <a ng-href=\"https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204\" class=\"ng-binding\" href=\"https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204\" style=\"color: #2e74b5; text-decoration: none;\">https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204</a>\n    <br>\n</p>\n\n<p>\n    <strong>Facility Address:</strong>\n    <br>\n    <span ng-bind-html=\"serviceRequest.formattedFacilityAddress\" class=\"ng-binding\">Metro Street<br>B 23 Street<br>Noida City, NCR State 110092</span>\n    <br>\n</p>\n\n<p class=\"ng-binding\">\n    <strong>Client Contact Information</strong>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Name:</strong> Sumit Vueops Account\n    <br>\n    <strong>Email:</strong> sumitka@vueops.com\n    <br>\n    <strong>Phone Number:</strong> 999-687-4668\n</p>\n\n<p>\n    <strong>STEP 2:</strong>\n    When the repair work is complete we ask that you respond to this email with the following information and a photo of the completed work:\n    <br>\n</p>\n<p>\n    <strong>Work Performed</strong>\n    <br>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Root Cause:</strong>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Repair Date:</strong>\n</p>\n\n<p>\n    \n </p>\n<div class=\"footer\" style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'FrnkGothITC Bk BT', 'Calibri', 'Arial', sans-serif; color: #999999; letter-spacing: 2pt;\"><p>Thank You, <br>Powered by <a href=\"www.vueops.com\" style=\"color: #2e74b5; text-decoration: none;\">VueOps</a><br>Know Your Building Inside Out<sup>TM<sup></sup></sup></p></div>\n</body>\n</html>\n", "body-plain"=>"Hello,\n\nA new Warranty Ticket has been issued for Email Subject Test edit for Sumit's Test.\nPlease follow the steps below to resolve this issue.\n\nSTEP 1:\nContact the client contact noted below for scheduling your inspection and repair. You may contact the client by phone or by replying-all to this email.\n\nWarranty Ticket Details:\n\nTicket #: SUM-EST-0204\n\nClient: Sumit's Test\n\nFacility: Email Subject Test edit\n\nProject: 118 docs\n\nTitle: Perferendis voluptat\n\nDescription: In excepteur aliquid\n\nLocation: Sed sint nihil moles\n\nPriority: Emergency\n\nYou can view the ticket details here:\n\nhttps://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204 ( https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204 )\n\nFacility Address:\n\nMetro Street\nB 23 Street\nNoida City, NCR State 110092\n\nClient Contact Information\n\nName: Sumit Vueops Account\n\nEmail: sumitka@vueops.com\n\nPhone Number: 999-687-4668\n\nSTEP 2:\nWhen the repair work is complete we ask that you respond to this email with the following information and a photo of the completed work:\n\nWork Performed\n\nRoot Cause:\n\nRepair Date:\n\nThank You,\nPowered by VueOps ( www.vueops.com )\nKnow Your Building Inside OutTM", "from"=>"VueOps Warranty Ticket <service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com>", "message-headers"=>"[[\"Mime-Version\",\"1.0\"],[\"Content-Type\",\"multipart/alternative; boundary=\\\"0d4b5135bbc71f7078e98fd7ee7355506fb2c219e22a702a301bd7123e55\\\"\"],[\"Subject\",\"Warranty Ticket SUM-EST-0204 for Email Subject Test edit for Sumit's Test has been issued to you for coordination\"],[\"From\",\"VueOps Warranty Ticket <service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com>\"],[\"To\",\"service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com\"],[\"In-Reply-To[]\",\"20230113183151.bad48c4ced209202@mg.vueops-qa.com\"],[\"Message-Id\",\"<20230113183151.74967e8866be2d25@mg.vueops-qa.com>\"],[\"Date\",\"Fri, 13 Jan 2023 18:31:51 +0000\"],[\"Sender\",\"service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com\"]]", "recipient"=>"service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com", "sender"=>"VueOps Warranty Ticket <service-requests-qa@mg.vueops-qa.com>", "signature"=>"88d9f1b2a5f75668a0436c39050bbccd194485cd4a3b8369d2025311c87c87aa", "stripped-html"=>"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\">\n<style>body {\nfont-family: 'Calibri', 'Arial', sans-serif;\n}\nimg {\noutline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body style=\"font-family: 'Calibri', 'Arial', sans-serif;\">\n<table align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"logo\" width=\"100%\"><tr><td align=\"left\"><img src=\"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dpr-email-assets/VueOPS-logo-full-color-ps.png\" style=\"outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: 120px;\"></td></tr></table>\n<p></p>\n<p>\n    Hello,\n</p>\n<p class=\"ng-binding\">\n    A new Warranty Ticket has been issued for Email Subject Test edit for Sumit's Test.\n    <strong>Please follow the steps below to resolve this issue.</strong>\n</p>\n<p>\n    <br>\n    <strong>STEP 1:</strong>\n    Contact the client contact noted below for scheduling your inspection and repair. You may contact the client by phone or by replying-all to this email.\n    <br>\n</p>\n<p class=\"ng-binding\">\n    <strong style=\"font-size: 1.1em;\">Warranty Ticket Details:</strong>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Ticket #:</strong> SUM-EST-0204\n    <br>\n    <strong>Client:</strong> Sumit's Test\n    <br>\n    <strong>Facility:</strong> Email Subject Test edit\n    <br>\n    <strong>Project:</strong> 118 docs\n    <br>\n    <strong>Title:</strong> Perferendis voluptat\n    <br>\n    <strong>Description:</strong> In excepteur aliquid\n    <br>\n    <strong>Location:</strong> Sed sint nihil moles\n    <br>\n    <strong>Priority:</strong> Emergency\n    <br>\n    <string>You can view the ticket details here:</string>\n    <br><br>\n    <a ng-href=\"https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204\" class=\"ng-binding\" href=\"https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204\" style=\"color: #2e74b5; text-decoration: none;\">https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204</a>\n    <br>\n</p>\n\n<p>\n    <strong>Facility Address:</strong>\n    <br>\n    <span ng-bind-html=\"serviceRequest.formattedFacilityAddress\" class=\"ng-binding\">Metro Street<br>B 23 Street<br>Noida City, NCR State 110092</span>\n    <br>\n</p>\n\n<p class=\"ng-binding\">\n    <strong>Client Contact Information</strong>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Name:</strong> Sumit Vueops Account\n    <br>\n    <strong>Email:</strong> sumitka@vueops.com\n    <br>\n    <strong>Phone Number:</strong> 999-687-4668\n</p>\n\n<p>\n    <strong>STEP 2:</strong>\n    When the repair work is complete we ask that you respond to this email with the following information and a photo of the completed work:\n    <br>\n</p>\n<p>\n    <strong>Work Performed</strong>\n    <br>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Root Cause:</strong>\n    <br>\n    <strong>Repair Date:</strong>\n</p>\n\n<p>\n    \n </p>\n<div class=\"footer\" style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'FrnkGothITC Bk BT', 'Calibri', 'Arial', sans-serif; color: #999999; letter-spacing: 2pt;\"><p>Thank You, <br>Powered by <a href=\"www.vueops.com\" style=\"color: #2e74b5; text-decoration: none;\">VueOps</a><br>Know Your Building Inside Out<sup>TM<sup></sup></sup></p></div>\n</body>\n</html>\n", "stripped-signature"=>"Work Performed\n\nRoot Cause:\n\nRepair Date:\n\nThank You,\nPowered by VueOps ( www.vueops.com )\nKnow Your Building Inside OutTM", "stripped-text"=>"Hello,\n\nA new Warranty Ticket has been issued for Email Subject Test edit for Sumit's Test.\nPlease follow the steps below to resolve this issue.\n\nSTEP 1:\nContact the client contact noted below for scheduling your inspection and repair. You may contact the client by phone or by replying-all to this email.\n\nWarranty Ticket Details:\n\nTicket #: SUM-EST-0204\n\nClient: Sumit's Test\n\nFacility: Email Subject Test edit\n\nProject: 118 docs\n\nTitle: Perferendis voluptat\n\nDescription: In excepteur aliquid\n\nLocation: Sed sint nihil moles\n\nPriority: Emergency\n\nYou can view the ticket details here:\n\nhttps://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204 ( https://sumit-s-test.vueops-qa.com/service_requests/sum-est-0204 )\n\nFacility Address:\n\nMetro Street\nB 23 Street\nNoida City, NCR State 110092\n\nClient Contact Information\n\nName: Sumit Vueops Account\n\nEmail: sumitka@vueops.com\n\nPhone Number: 999-687-4668\n\nSTEP 2:\nWhen the repair work is complete we ask that you respond to this email with the following information and a photo of the completed work:\n", "subject"=>"Warranty Ticket SUM-EST-0204 for Email Subject Test edit for Sumit's Test has been issued to you for coordination", "timestamp"=>"1673638018", "token"=>"90ec0b4c8e14caf44f4bc7259699e8cefdff521b15985ebdfa"}
```

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is it possible that it is not encoding it as base64? Did you check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html?

Comment: Thanks, @Brian, for your response! I have resolved my issue and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to figure out the solution. I'm getting `Content-Type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which needs to convert using `URI.decode_www_form`. Now I'm getting the correct JSON request body.